# How to tell the client that the data type is unsupported

Tags: rest, http-headers

Writing a RESTful API, I've stumbled on a problem.
If the client POST/PUT some data in a format **not supported** by the API, how should the server alert the client?

*E.g.:* Client POSTed some data in a QueryString format

```
fieldA=foo&fieldB=bar
```

But the server accepts only JSON, so the data should be POSTed like this:

```
{"fieldA": "foo", "fieldB": "bar"}
```

Currently, I'm sending a *415 status code* (PHP code):

```
header("HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type", true, 415);
```

But this doesn't tell the client which media type the API accepts/consumes.
Besides, is this enough or *the right way* to fail the request?

The question is, in a RESTful API, what is the best way to tell the client that the data sent to server is in an unsupported media type, and how the server tells the client what is supported/expected?

**PS:** I'm writing this application in PHP but I'm interested in the behavior, not the actual implementation.
Because the logic is the same everywhere, responses in any language are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to distinguish between these two types of errors:

1. **400** Bad Request - is not the same as:
2. **415** Unsupported Media Type

When a request with unsupported media type is sent 415 should be returned. Since there's no header that indicates what media types are accepted by the endpoint and precise info is needed, a detailed message may be returned in response's body. To be short, return 415 with a messages *XML and JSON are supported*. In most frameworks returned error can be caught and wrapped. Remember only to **always** return error message in the same format so the consumer may easily parse it.

When a request is sent in a valid format (JSON) but e.g. a single field is sent as an instance of a String and is required to be an Integer, **400** should be returned with a detailed message.

Hope that helps you.

Comment: In case of a 415, is there any header that the server should return to tell the expected media types? If not, should the server send this information in the response content? Is there any standard or format that this message should follow?

Comment: No, there's not. As I wrote in my answer. This kind of message can be easily carried in the body. There's no such format. You can introduce own but as I wrote, be consistent for all error messages.

Comment: "You can introduce own but as I wrote, be consistent for all error messages." Perfect... Thanks... ;D